# Reusing function on window resize/load

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, that check window on load/resize and accroding to variable `MOBILE_WIDTH` it runs (or not) the function. But it follows the obvious issue that when restarting the same function it reruns each initialization inside, like .forEach method, so when we click the same heading after resizing the console log shows that we clicked it multiple times. How to avoid this? 
And the [codepen here](https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/GvgydW).

```js
let window_handlers = ['load', 'resize'];
let h1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
const MOBILE_WIDTH = 600;

window_handlers.map(handler => {
 window.addEventListener(handler, ()=>{
  console.log(handler)
  if(window.innerWidth <= MOBILE_WIDTH) {   
   test(true);
  } else {
   test(false);
  }
 })
})
let test = (statement) => {
 if(statement) {
  Array.from(h1).forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    console.log('clicked')
   })
  })
 }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FE5F55;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
h1:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="headers">
 <h1>Header 1</h1>
 <h1>Header 2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you're not removing event listeners before adding them back in.

Use removeEventListener to remove the click event in the first line of your resize method.

```
let window_handlers = ['load', 'resize'];
let h1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
const MOBILE_WIDTH = 600;

window_handlers.map(handler => {
    window.addEventListener(handler, ()=>{
        console.log(handler)
        Array.from(h1).forEach(element => {
            element.removeEventListener('click', click);
        })

        if(window.innerWidth <= MOBILE_WIDTH) {         
            test(true);
        } else {
            test(false);
        }
    })
})
let test = (statement) => {
    if(statement) {
        Array.from(h1).forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('click', click);
        })
    }
}
function click() { console.log('clicked'); }
```

I have not tested this however you should understand the concept.

Comment: the click event is an example, the code consists of much more functions inside. I dont want it to replace just the click event.

Comment: The approach is the same for every listener you have in there

Comment: There are a couple of forEach methods, which are not event listeners.

Comment: well the multiples clicks question is answered , the other issues was not asked